# What is the length of an open interval and how do you prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If an open interval does not contain its endpoints, why does its length is the same as a closed interval with the same endpoints? For example, $d((3,6)) = d([3,6])$.

Comment: the distance between any two points $a,b$ on the number line is $|b-a|$ this is very intrinsic to calculus. If you know that $b>a$ you can drop the absolute values $|b-a|=b-a$

Comment: It's by definition

Comment: @N8tron I know what distance is. I didn't know that single points have no length as Eric Wofsey mentioned. So I did not understand why an open interval has the same length of a closed one.

Comment: What's the area of a rectangle under $f(x)=1$ on the interval $[a,b]$ in terms of calculus? What's the area under the same $f$ on $(a,b)$ in terms of calculus? The whole idea is lines don't have area so they don't affect area. Points don't have length

Comment: Euclid's completely unsatisfying definition of a a point is *"that which has no part”*

Comment: it is a convention that the distance from a point to itself is 0. But, there are generalization of distances (called partial metrics) where the distance from a point to itself may be positive. While you probably need not worry about that, here are a couple of links: https://nyaspubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1749-6632.1994.tb44144.x and http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/pmetric/monthly708-718.pdf

Comment: @N8tron and Mirko , thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of an interval $(a,b)$ (or $[a,b]$, or $(a,b]$, or $[a,b)$) is defined to be $b-a$.  This is just a definition, so it requires no proof.  Intuitively, it should make sense: if you think of the interval as being a "stick" cut out from the number line, then it would be $b-a$ units long.  We don't care whether the interval contains its endpoints because a single point has no length.

The following intuition may help.  Suppose you have a ruler, with lengths marked in centimeters along it.  If you want to measure a length of $c$ centimeters, you would usually just measure from the start of the ruler to the point marked $c$.  However, you could also measure from a point marked $a$ to a point marked $b$, as long as $b-a=c$.  The reason is that you could just shift the ruler forwards by $a$ centimeters, so the point that was marked $a$ is now at the start of the ruler and the point that was marked $b$ is now marked $b-a$.

A vast generalization of this notion of "length of an interval" is [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) on $\mathbb{R}$, which is a way of defining the "length" of much more complicated sets than just an interval.  In the context of Lebesgue measure, depending on your definitions, it may be a theorem that the length of $(a,b)$ is $b-a$.  But in calculus or basic analysis, this is usually just taken as a definition.

Comment: it does not make sense because, for example if you have $(3,6)$ so $3,6\notin(3,6)$.

Comment: I don't understand your objection.

Comment: $[3,6]$ and $(3,6)$ have the same length pretty much following from definition

Comment: It does make sense because, by definition, an open interval does not contain its endpoints.

Comment: @EricWofsey If an open interval does not contain its endpoints, why does $d((3,6)) = d([3,6])$?

Comment: A single point (or two points) has no length.

Comment: @EricWofsey So this is the real reason. Some people here think that I don't understand what distance is..I just didn't know that single points have no length.

Comment: @MorHaham: Well, what do you expect people to think when you don't tell them the reasoning behind your question?

Comment: @EricWofsey Right...

Answer (score 0):

This question is more related to measure theory than topology. The most standard measure on the collection of sets generated by open intervals is Lebesgue measure where $\mu([a,b])=b-a$. You can associate a measure with any right continuous function F such that $\mu_F([a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$. There's no correct answer for the measure of an interval, there's lots of different ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt of intuitively justifying it to you. Think about the distance between a point and the origin.

- In $\mathbb{R}^3$ take $P(x,y,z)$ has distance $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
- In $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the $xy$--plane) take $P(x,y)$ has distance $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
- In $\mathbb{R}^1$ (the number line ) take $P(x)$ has distance $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

So on the number line the distance between any point $P(x)$ and the origin is $|x|$. Now if you want to find the distnce between two points $P(x)$ and $Q(y)$ on the number line first consider their difference $R(x-y)$ it will have the same distance from $0$ as $P$ has from $Q$ so $|b-a|$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$ on the number line. When $b>a$ you can drop the absolute values $|b-a|=b-a$